# Want xib file to cover whole screen instead of covering top left ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xib

I am making an ios app and using xib files instead of storyboards. At first I didn't even have to use auto layout everything worked fine for all iphone devices in portrait. But as soon as I added a launch screen through assests only the the iphone 5 has the correct layout (because xib file size is set to 4 inch). But any greater screen size and only the top left hand corner is covered like below:

[image]

I want the view to cover the whole screen. There is a view at the top but I cannot add any constraints to it. Inside the view there is an imageview that is supposed to cover the whole screen. So I added 4 constraints and pinned the 4 sides to 0 so the imageview should cover the whole screen. But it still does not work. What can I do so the whole screen will be covered?

Comment: before _launch screen_ the screen just scaled up by iOS and you did not do the proper iPhone6/6s screen support; now with the _launch screen_ iOS does not do the up-sampling, you need to set up the interface with auto-layout properly to adopt your layout to multiple size of screens – that is why your app looks to be at the top-left corner; it is not xib vs. storyboard issue, the constraints have to be deployed only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried set the frame?

```
NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"xibFileName" owner:nil options:nil];        
[[array objectAtIndex:0] setFrame:self.view.frame]; // Trick here: set the main view frame
```

This worked in my case:

```
// Create a Container
    UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// Add .xib file on top of the screen
    NSArray *array = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"xibFileName" owner:nil options:nil];        
    [container addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:0]];

// Add container to main view
    [self.view addSubview:container];
```

About the itens inside of .xib file you have to set the constraints there.